# ie Context menu - opening URL using selected text

Tags: url, contextmenu

I'm very unfamiliar with Java (mainly use VBA), and am trying to highlight text "CJ46216409", right click and open a new page using that string in the URL.

(Intranet site)
"http://maintrakau/OnForward/Wharf/Enquiry/Job_Enquiry.asp?jobno=CJ46216409".

I have added the new item to the context menu and am trying to work out the code needed.

Have been researching building strings, but can't get the right combination for this to work (also don't know how to confirm if i'm setting the text variable correctly). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var text  = document.selection.createRange().htmlText

window.open('http://maintrakau/OnForward/Wharf/Enquiry/Job_Enquiry.asp?jobno=' + text ,'_blank');

</script>
```

Comment: using ie11 so changed to var text = window.getSelection(); this seems to be failing, even when using it and window.alert(selObj); after to try and confirm I have the text. The selected text looks to be in a table.

Comment: *window.alert(text)